# BareMessage="Cannot create an abstract class."

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Cannot create an abstract class.

Source Error:

```
Line 150:      <providers>
Line 151:        <clear/>
Line 152:        <add name="NDMSMembershipProvider"
                          type="CSW.Web.Security.NDMSMemberProvider"/>
Line 153:      </providers>
Line 154:    </membership>
```

Source File: `C:\Dev\CSW2\src\CSW.Web\web.config    Line: 152`

can someone help me. I am going crazy

Answer (score 0):

Right, you can't instantiate an abstract class.

Make a new class that inherits your abstract class and use that one.